# CSS or Javascript to disable text selection highlighting from CTRL + A

Tags: javascript, css, html, events

**Note:** this questions is different from [How to disable text selection highlighting using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

Before ask I read the discussion history from above question. All works fine, except I can allow `CTRL+A` (Select All) only works inside input elments.

That's because I'm deploying my HTML5 app on Desktop and I wish the same behavior from a GUI/Forms application.

What would be the starting point? Try to bind at all elements with `keypress` event and observe CTRL + A `keyCode`? The disadvantage of this approach would have to be controlling everything and take care on re-renders.

I prefer a CSS solution, but any idea is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

**@EDIT:** I found this ulgy solution, but working:

```
$(document).keydown(function(objEvent) {
    if (objEvent.ctrlKey) {
        if ((objEvent.keyCode === 65) || (objEvent.keyCode == 97)) {
            if ($(objEvent.target).not("input").disableTextSelect().length) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `keypress` won't grab CTRL but `keydown` should work.

Comment: Are you trying to *allow* Ctrl+A, or *disallow* Ctrl+A?

Comment: Disallow on `<body>` and allow inside `<input>`

Comment: The question is not clear. You want the text to be selected with Ctrl+A only?

Comment: Why in the entire world do you want to do this? It's not your business to try an circumvent fundamental browser behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible Duplicate.

If you are allowed to use jquery, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403748/how-can-i-disable-ctrla-select-all-using-jquery-in-a-browser) is the answer you are looking for.

65 is ascii for 'A' and 97 for 'a' if you want to account for both.

```
$(function(){   
    $(document).keydown(function(objEvent) {

            if (objEvent.ctrlKey) {
                if ($(objEvent.target).not('input')){
                    if (objEvent.keyCode == 65 || objEvent.keyCode == 97) {                         
                        objEvent.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            }        
    });
});
```

edit: modified based on your comment to allow for input.

edit 2: if you include jQuery UI you can use disableSelection() instead of disableTextSelect()
otherwise try [this.](http://code.jdempster.com/jQuery.DisableTextSelect/jquery.disable.text.select.js)

edit 3: Sorry, disableSelection() is deprecated in jQuery 1.9 see [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959336/why-is-disableselection-deprecated). Try this simple hack instead of disableSelection(). replace                      `objEvent.disableTextSelect();` with `objEvent.preventDefault();` above.

edit 4: made it a bit cleaner.

Comment: I try this example and result `TypeError: objEvent.disableTextSelect is not a function`

Comment: I have injected this plugin and tested again http://code.jdempster.com/jQuery.DisableTextSelect/jquery.disable.text.select.js - don't works

Comment: @AllysondePaula which version of jQuery are you including? did you try the second approach (including jQuery UI and using disableSelection())? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: jQuery v1.9.1 and jQuery UI - v1.10.1 - with `disableSelection()` not worked too

Comment: I found one solution - it's ugly, but works, see my edit. I will accept your asnwer as correct, because solve almost part of the problem.

Comment: did you get a chance to try preventDefault();?

Comment: I've tried yor example, have different behavior from my edit. In your I can't select content inside input (And I wish allow user select all text inside all input elements)

Answer (score -2):

```css
user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
```

Use the above CSS properties to stop that behavior.

Comment: The OP was specifically asking for a solution that works for `Ctrl+A`.

Comment: Duplicate question and was answered here with the same answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598070/cross-browser-disable-the-user-select-ctrl-a

Comment: My impression is that the OP wants to allow Ctrl+A: "All works fine, except I can *allow* CTRL+A (Select All) only works inside input elments."