# Cannot click or select span elements, after a canvas is focused in HTML - debugging?

Tags: javascript, html, css, debugging

I don't often work with HTML these days, and I'm working with some JS libraries that manipulate canvas. I got done all that I needed - but I just realized, that

- When the webpage starts, all text is selectable (titles, subtitles, notifications etc - basically all text in spans and divs)
- Then, I typically click on the canvas and interact with it
- But, if after clicking the canvas, I try to go to, say, the title span, and click on it to select - the text is not selectable anymore (and no text on the webpage is anymore, apart from text form inputs)

So, I tried looking into this, and found:

[HTML input fields does not get focus when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724749/html-input-fields-does-not-get-focus-when-clicked)

> The root cause of the problem is `disableSelection()`. It is causing all the problems, but removing it is not a solution, as (at least in 2016 or slightly before), on touch-screen devices, you "have" to use this if you want to be able to move objects with jQuery.

So, disableSelection is apparently jQuery, but so far I have just used vanilla javascript in my project (I think, but some of the libraries I use might use jQuery).

Anyways, I thought - before I try to blindly copy/paste online code, in an attempt to restore selectability, - could I somehow confirm through the DOM inspector in the browser, that an element is selectable or not? Say, here is how my Firefox Inspector form Web Developer Tools looks like:

[image]

Is there something accessible in the Inspector, like a CSS property, to tell me if an object is selectable? If not, can I quickly run a JavaScript one-liner in the browser Console, and find out the selectability status of an element?

Comment: This answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/13959496/5869805

Comment: Thanks @burkay - that link mentions `user-select` et al., so I tried to select an element, then click on Computed tab on the right hand side of the Inspector, tried to filter for "select", and got nothing; so I cannot confirm nothing yet.

Comment: Hey @sdbbs. I'm using Firefox. I opened up the jsfiddle link on that answer. As you did, I checked the computed tab. It was showing `user-select: none` and text was not selectable. Using filter styles tab, I unchecked that rule. It falled back to `-webkit-user-select: none;`, text was still not selectable. But it did not show up on computed tab. Unchecked that one as well, falled back to `-moz-user-select: -moz-none;`. Text was still not selectable and nothing showed up on computed tab. Looks like browser specific rules are rendered on page but not listed on computed tab.

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks to the comment of @burkay, I got it - indeed, it is about `user-select`. So, in Firefox,

- right-click on an element then choose Inspect Element, then
- Right-click on the entry (corresponding to this element, autoselected) in the Inspector, and choose "Use in Console"
- Then you will get a `temp1` variable in Console, which you can query:

[image]

Note that CSS properties end up as properties of `.style` property of the element, however their names do not include hyphens anymore, but are instead CamelCase - so for `user-select` in CSS file, we have `.style.userSelect` in Console. (also, note that `.mozUserSelect` tracks/copies the values of `userSelect`)

Above is the log that I got for my problem; at start, the object has `.style.userSelect` set to empty string, and it is unselectable; then I tried setting it to "auto", and it remained unselectable; finally I set it to "text" - and at that point, the text became selectable (credit to [@RaduSimionescu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959336/why-is-disableselection-deprecated/13959496#comment26070753_13959496))